# PL SQL extract cuts first character from CDATA

Tags: plsql, oracle11g, xml-parsing, extract, cdata

On database I have column with clobs. In this column I save forms with xml. When doing:

```
select dataclob from table_name;
```

I get xml with all data. Example:

```
<FormData>
<Field name="field_name1"><Value><![CDATA[short string]]></Value></Field>
<Field name="field_name2"><Value><![CDATA[<Records>
  <Record><Entry name="province">WOJEWÓDZTWO 1</Entry></Record>......really long xml in cdata with more entries, records</Records>]]></Value></Field>
</FormData>
```

When doing simple:

```
select extract(xmltype(dataclob), '//Field[@name="field_name2"]') from table_name;
```

the function cuts first character in cdata. Result:

```
<Value><![CDATA[Records>
          <Record><Entry name="province">WOJEWÓDZTWO 1</Entry></Record>......really long xml in cdata with more entries, records</Records>]]>
</Value>
```

In this clob there is a lot of fields. It can be really long but each one has different size. Also when field with cdata and xml in it is more than one it cuts character only from one field with cdata.

It happens once in a while. Database is EE 11.2.0.4.0. Someone knows why this happen?

Also something like this for the same data is causing issue:

```
select val 
from XMLTable('descendant::Field[@name="field_name"][position() = 1]/Value'
passing dataclob_changed_to_xml
columns val clob path 'text()'); -- or path '/'
```

It returns:

```
Records>
          <Record><Entry name="province">WOJEWÓDZTWO 1</Entry></Record>......really long xml in cdata with more entries, records</Records>
```

Comment: Is it happening for you with the sample you showed (though the XPath would need `/Value` to get that anyway)? Or it it intermittent even for the same CLOB?

Comment: It doesn't matter if I add /Value or not. It cuts the first character.  I used to replace CDATA with '' and get only result from inside. What is interesting and really frustrating that extract is one of the examples. When I use xmltable the same things happens. It was changed to xmltable and the Path is with /Value. When I use xmltable string returned is without cdata but also there is first character missing.

Comment: But intermittently, even for the same CLOB? Which client or application do you see this through - even SQL\*Plus or SQL Developer?

Comment: I test it on SQL Developer. Firstly I do the select dataclob from table_name; And there is all characters, then I'm doing select statement with extract on dataclob and it cuts first character, then I'm doing select stetement with xmltable and it also cuts first character. It happens randomly on different clobs or I don't see a pattern.

Comment: If you only see it in that client then it might be worth trying with the latest version, if you aren't already on that. Weird though. Is the character it loses always `<`?

Comment: It happens also when we use application. Application executes database procedure which manipulates on xml and uses extract or xmltable. And also it happens. It cuts the first character. It loses the first one, doesn't matter what is first. Sometimes it helps adding space somewhere before field with or just space< but why it happens. I thought that maybe cdata have some limits but it is weird behaviour. I also thought about some patches maybe was added to oracle database. I'm running out of ideas.

Comment: Sounds like bug 14164191, but that's supposedly fixed in 11.2.0.4, according to doc 14164191.8 - though the bug report only mentions 12.1. You might need to raise a service request to see if this is the same problem and if there is a fix. Good luck.